# iPad iTunes Animation

Tags: iphone, animation, itunes

Within the iTunes Music Store app on the iPad, if you select an album, a modal view flips out of the album over to the middle of the screen. Is this a built in animation or a custom built one? How would I go about replicating it?

This can be seen about 30 seconds into [this video](http://www.apple.com/ipad/guided-tours/#itunes).

Thanks

Comment: I guess the video is update. the link points to a video `This good` it end after `28 seconds`. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a built-in animation. Create the View Controller you want to display in the modal view and then present it within a Navigation Controller.

```
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalEvent" bundle:nil];
    viewController.delegate = self;

    modalNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    modalNavController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    modalNavController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:modalNavController animated:YES];

    [viewController release];
```