# flip pop up 360 degree and display image in it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I want to flip a pop up in a view and display an image in it, just like it is done in jetsetter app.
Visit link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xna2YVgXY7c at 1.04 min.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a 3D Affine transform to the layer and animate it using Core Animation. UIView animations only do 2D ones.

Comment: i got some solution steal i don't know how to use it any one will give me the code for it......link as below  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605959/implement-custom-animation-to-present-modal-view-from-specified-view-on-ipad